# XML Error, 'Data at the root level is invalid'

Tags: xml, vb.net, winforms, serialization

I'm saving a list of objects as XML with the following code in in a Windows Form Project.

```
SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
Dim Path = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
Dim file As StreamWriter
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Path, "")
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Path, False)
Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Player)))
ser.Serialize(file, PlayerList)
file.WriteLine(ser)
file.Close()
```

And reading it back in with:

```
OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
Dim Path = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
Dim reader As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Player)))
Dim filereader As New System.IO.StreamReader(Path)
PlayerList = reader.Deserialize(filereader)
```

The file looks correct, here's what comes out when I have two objects in the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPlayer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Player>
    <Name>Kennedy Igboananike</Name>
    <Control>999</Control>
    <Tackling>999</Tackling>
    <Passing>999</Passing>
    <Heading>999</Heading>
    <Shooting>1000</Shooting>
    <Speed>731</Speed>
    <Age>30</Age>
  </Player>
  <Player>
    <Name>Dean Wormall</Name>
    <Control>408</Control>
    <Tackling>390</Tackling>
    <Passing>579</Passing>
    <Heading>428</Heading>
    <Shooting>449</Shooting>
    <Speed>719</Speed>
    <Age>17</Age>
  </Player>
</ArrayOfPlayer>System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer
```

But when attempting to read it back, I get the error:

> *Data at the root level is invalid. Line X, position 17*

which corresponds to just after `/ArrayOfPlayer` and the start of `System.Xml`... etc.

From what I can tell, looking at other examples of xml, that final `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` shouldn't be there and appears to be causing the problem, but I can't work out from my code why it's being attached at the end. I'm trying this with completely blank files so it's nothing from a previous write.

The code is taken from various places, so it's a bit of a mish-mash, since I was struggling to work out how to serialize/deserialize a list of objects.

My class is in a separate file and looks like this:

```
<Serializable>
Public Class Player
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Control As Integer
    Public Property Tackling As Integer
    Public Property Passing As Integer
    Public Property Heading As Integer
    Public Property Shooting As Integer
    Public Property Speed As Integer
    Public Property Age As Integer

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Path, "")
My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Path, False)
```

- If you want to overwrite the existing data, specifying `false` as the append argument is enough.
- You don't need `OpenTextFileWriter`, you can simply pass the selected file path to a `StreamReader` constructor.

The error:

```
file.WriteLine(ser)
```

This writes the type of `ser` (`System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`) to the end of the file. You don't want that.

Here I'm declaring a new `SaveFileDialog()` (I'm not using a `SaveFileDialog` component, just the class object - you don't need the UI component to open a Dialog) with a [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) statement, so it will be disposed of right after the code in the `Using` block completes.
The same applies to the StreamWriter: when its current operations complete, it will be disposed and the stream flushed:

```
Using sfd As New SaveFileDialog()
    sfd.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml"
    sfd.RestoreDirectory = True
    If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Using writer As New StreamWriter(sfd.FileName, False)
            Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Player)))
            ser.Serialize(writer, PlayerList)
        End Using
    End If
End Using
```

To read it back, do the opposite:
`DirectCast` is used because `XmlSerializer.Deserialize` returns an object type.

```
Dim PlayerList As New List(Of Player)
Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog()
    ofd.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml"
    ofd.RestoreDirectory = True
    If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Player)))
        Using reader As New StreamReader(ofd.FileName)
            PlayerList = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(reader), List(Of Player))
        End Using
    End If
End Using
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Works perfectly. Accepted as correct answer :)